# get select values from dyanamically created html

Tags: jquery

How to get selected values on submitSkills click
I am adding option value in my javascript

```
  $('#tabpage_4').append("<div class='side-by-side clearfix'><table><tr><td><h3>Skills & Expertise  :</h3></td><td id='skillstd'><select data-placeholder='Type skills here'  multiple class='chosen-select' style='width:300px;' tabindex='18' id='multiple-label-example'></select></td></tr></table><div style='padding-left:23%;padding-top:3%;'><input type='button' class='gblredbutton' value='Save' onclick='javascript:submitSkills(event);'/></div></div>");

function submitSkills(e){
    var skillID=$(e).attr("id");
    alert(skillID);

}
```

Comment: Did you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Bz28j/4/

Comment: Yes Sir same...but i m adding option value in my javascript

Comment: Thanks Sir it's working asesome...U same my time

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#multiple-label-example').val()
```

Comment: +1, this looks okay to me. Not sure why it was downvoted

Comment: Yes, the selected value of a select with ID defined! What's the matter?

Comment: @BenM my understanding is that he wants the values selected (hence the question title), could be wrong though

Comment: Hmm, big assumption: `$(e).attr("id");`?

Comment: @BenM yeah that's why I was unsure. I was going on the question title and the first sentence rather than the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the attribute of an event, not the `select` element that triggered the event.

First of all, please don't use intrusive event handlers. You can quite easily hook into the `onchange` function at the point you create the element.

For example:

```
$('#tabpage_4').append("<div class='side-by-side clearfix'><table><tr><td><h3>Skills & Expertise  :</h3></td><td id='skillstd'><select data-placeholder='Type skills here'  multiple class='chosen-select' style='width:300px;' tabindex='18' id='multiple-label-example'></select></td></tr></table><div style='padding-left:23%;padding-top:3%;'><input type='button' class='gblredbutton' value='Save' onclick='javascript:submitSkills(event);'/></div></div>");
$('#tabpage_4').find('select').on('change', function() {  
    var skillID = this.id;
    alert(skillID);
});
```

Comment: I tried this but on change is not executed alert is not coming and no error also

Comment: This works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/SYJGv/ You haven't added any options to the `select` element, which might explain why the event is never triggered.